# Javascript doesn't work if I invoke it as URL

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I want to run a Javascript file in my page. If I embed it as a script inside of the HTML, it works. I mean, the following code works fine:

```
<html>
    <script>
         ...
    </script>
</html>
```

But when I reference an URL source (with the `src` attribute), it doesn't work:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXX/myJavascript.js">
  </script>     
</html>
```

When I put the URL in my browser, the code is displayed.

EDIT: **Do I need some especial configuration in the Amazon S3 Servers in order to work with my Javascript files??? I just uploaded it and marked it as public resources, but I did nothing more.**

Comment: Maybe it is being served with the wrong mime type. Otherwise, it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, you need to set the MIME type when you upload to S3. How you do that will depend on how you are uploading the files. Also, what is the actual content of the .js? It's just the JavaScript code and not the `<script>` tag or anything, right?

Comment: The script it is just a facebook's dialog and a javascript SDK inicialization. I made the uploads files with the [S3 Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-2#)

Comment: According to the console's properties, the javascript content type is the next: **application/x-javascript**. It's that ok?

Comment: Are you serving up your page in the same protocol? (https)

Comment: My app it's in http protocol. But, do you think that can be a problem? I'm not sure if Heroku will let me change that.

Comment: I have changed the protocol of the javascripts's urls  but still doesn't work. I have changed the mime type of the javascript to text, but neither. The images served from S3 yes does work fine. I don't know what more tray.